# I just tried to build a simple server and client

Tags: java

Both ran successfully, but they skipped some parts, I don't know why. Here are the codes

Client:

```
package echoapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleEchoClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Simple Echo Client");

        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection.....");
            InetAddress localAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

            try (Socket clientSocket = new Socket(localAddress, 6000);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()))){
                System.out.println("Connected to server");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                while (true) {
                    System.out.print("Enter text: ");
                    String inputLine = scanner.nextLine();
                    if ("quit".equalsIgnoreCase(inputLine)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    out.println(inputLine);
                    String response = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Server response: " + response);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Handle exceptions
        }

    }

}
```

Server:

```
package echoapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleEchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Simple Echo Server");

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6000)){
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection.....");
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected to client");
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true)) {
                String inputLine;
                while((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Server: " + inputLine);
                    out.println(inputLine);
                }
            }    
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Handle exceptions
        }
    }

}
```

I should be able to type something in the client and get the response from the server. Like echo. I don't know why how to fix the try block to make all the codes ran through. The parts where the second try has a problem, and I couldn't make the second try block work.

Comment: what is the problem, can you post the error?

Comment: This is working for me without any issues

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't have them working. If they worked fine, it should promote a text said connected and I will be able to type any information. It is an echo thing that allows users to type in client and server will echo back whatever client side have sent.

Comment: I don't have the error because I didn't put anything in the catch yet. So here is my result for both codes:

Comment: it worked for me in that way, okay how are you executing this ?

Comment: Simple Echo Client
Waiting for connection.....                                                                              
                                                                                                                       Simple Echo Client
Waiting for connection.....

Comment: How?? Did you get the second try worked?

Comment: when client is waiting for connection, start the server, if you are ide like eclipse, you need two ides, or executes these two files in two different terminals

Comment: So i i will run the server first, and then client, they should have information like the one I just sent, waiting for connection, so once I run the client code, client should have ouput, like connected to server, and so does server, and then client would promote "enter text"  and I would be able to type and get what I just typed in server

Comment: Oh, I use netbeans

Comment: But the probelm is both codes seem to skip the second try, which means I fail to connect them

Comment: try in different terminals, it will works, understand how you can establish client server connection